# how to make variable value available in a separate function call

Tags: php

the scenario is like this, I have two cron jobs.
e.g

```
***** php myClass myFunction1
***** php myClass myFunction2
```

myFunction2 is supposed to send the data to a remote server which was being initialized to a variable within myFunction1

```
e.g

class myClass

private $testData = array();

public function myFunction1() {
    ..blah blah blah..
     //set data here
     $ths->testData = [some array];

}

public function myFunction2() {
    ..blah blah blah.
     //push data to remote server.
     var_dump($this->testData)
}
```

now the problem is, the data is not available in myFunction2, maybe because the function call is a different call in the crontab and it exist only on the first function call. Is there a way to access the data being set in myFunction1 once the myFunction2 gets executed ?
I have tried the $GLOBALS , it doesn't work. Session is also not working in CLI of php. I don't want to use database to store and pull data, because I will use it only for temporary purpose, but the data has to be accessible in both crontab calls

Comment: You're talking about two different invocations of the program. You can't share data between them, you need to store it using something like a flat file or a database.

Comment: I see, that's what i suspected.  there seem to be no other way but to use a storage db

Comment: Well, that or just have one cron job run both functions. You haven't explained why you  need to run two different cron jobs.

Comment: because I just had to. the codebase is too complex I only gave a few concepts of the issue I am facing. hard to explain. it actually has 28 cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

Try using cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
But then the problem becomes syncing up the two different cronjobs.

Comment: the issue am facing is not the sending of data to a remote server. I know how to use curl. the issue is getting the data which was initialized from the first cronjob task

Comment: The nature of cronjobs is that they run at different time intervals. How can you be sure the remote server is listening while the transmitting side is sending?